# Django installation admin page not getting

Tags: django, installation

I installed Django and created myproject & myapp by refer the tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_creating_project.htm

I got below output while run the command `$ python manage.py runserver`

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 05, 2018 - 06:32:21
Django version 1.11, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

But while I run the URL in the browser http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/, it shows "Unable to connect"

Comment: Are you running this on the same machine your browser is on?

Comment: Yes, I installed the Django project in my xampp and run the command "$ python manage.py runserver" inside $ cd var/www/myproject